# wp_query not returning my custom post

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I am using [these](https://github.com/Gizburdt/Wordpress-Cuztom-Helper/) helper classes to create a custom post but wp_query does not return any instances. Checked the source and as far as I can see the public has been set to true.

The query is the following:

```
  $numFetch=$multiple?100:1;
  $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => $numFetch,
      'search_post_title' => $data_source_name,
      'post-type' => 'any',
      'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC'
      );
  $args['search_post_title'] = $multiple?
    '.post_title LIKE \'' . esc_sql(like_escape($data_source_name)) . '%\'':
    '.post_title = \'' . esc_sql(like_escape($data_source_name)) . '\'';
  add_filter('posts_where', 'title_filter', 10, 2);
  $loop = new WP_Query($args);
  while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    var_dump($post);
  endwhile;
```

In funcitons.php I have

```
function title_filter($where, &$wp_query) {
  global $wpdb;
  if ($search_term = $wp_query->get('search_post_title')) {
    $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . $search_term;
  }
  return $where;
}
```

When I add a post with the same title it does show up. I will try to manually create a custom post and see if that shows up (leaving default public to true) but not sure if that is the problem. I'd like it to not show up in searches anyway unless I specify it but could not find a way to do this either (like `'exclude_from_search'=>true`)

**[UPDATE]**

```
Added the following code in functions.php:
function codex_custom_init() {
    $args = array(
      'public' => true,
      'label'  => 'Books'
    );
    register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
```

Then added a Book with the title: "a book", then changed the query code to:

```
$args['search_post_title'] = '.post_title LIKE \'%a book%\'';
```

But no items are returned.

If I add a post with the title "a book" then it does show up. Looks like 'post-type' => 'any' isn't doing what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just spent another hour trying to debug something because the shift key on my keyboard doesn't always work.

```
post-type != post_type
```

There should be an under score between post and type, not a hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this and see if it works:

```
function filter_search( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_search ) {
        $query->set('post_type', array('book'));
    };
    return $query;
};
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_search' );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was trying to search for any post type including custom post(s). If I add book and later want to search for writer than that filter would prevent it from showing up. 'post_type' => 'any' should let me find the post I'm looking for and does but since I made a typo it didn't